# Symbols tree view in Visual Studio Code ("not" Visual studio) in mac

Tags: macos, editor, visual-studio-code, symbols

I'm opening python project in Visual Studio Code. But I couldn't get a way to see symbols in currently opened file. Is there a view available in Visual Studio Code.

I'm using version 1.4.0

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for this also.
Besides source code this is also useful for navigation in medium to large Markdown documents.

According to this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5605 this feature is not available yet, vote it to get it in the pipeline faster.

Ctrl+Shift+O is currently available which gives a flat list of symbols in the current file. It is useful for small source files but a tree would be much easier to work with for larger files.

Another issue with Ctrl+Shift+O is that when you filter the results are not ordered by their position in the source file, IMHO this behavior is ok when you search the whole workspace but when searching in the currently opened file I would like the results sorted by their position in the file.

**EDIT 2023-11-13**

There is the Outline view, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_outline-view, which shows a tree with symbols from the current file ... can be combined with "Follow Cursor" and Ctrl+Shift+O filtering